# change file name Isolated Storage windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

i would like when i create a file in the IO by using the StreamWriter something like

```
streamReaderLOL = new StreamReader(
  new IsolatedStorageFileStream("test\\parameter.txt", FileMode.Open, UserPlace));
```

where parameter is a variable
i have try smth like

```
"test\\"+parameter".txt" etc but seems not to work.
```

so my question is : is it possible ?

ty a lot

Comment: "Seems not to work" is very vague. It would really help if you'd provide a complete method at least, and say what behaviour you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `"test\\" + parameter + ".txt"` should be absolutely fine. It's only constructing a string to pass in as the arugment, after all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a directory within IsolatedStorage you must first create the directory before trying to use it.

```
using (var isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    if (!isoStore.DirectoryExists("test"))
    {
        isoStore.CreateDirectory("test");
    }

    isoStore.CreateFile("test\\" + param + ".txt");
}
```